# How to build "akmod-r8168" driver kernel module package for fedora?

Tags: linux, fedora, rhel, drivers, realtek

Debian/Ubuntu has Realtek proprietary driver r8168 as "r8168-dkms". Which build driver module with every kernel update. Fedora has similar with "akmod". This is how they deliver NVIDIA driver. But they haven't provided "akmod-r8168" package. So, I am thinking to build it on my own. How can I build "akmod-r8168" package from "r8168-dkms" driver?
"kmod-r8168" driver exist. But kmod don't rebuild with every kernel update but "akmod" does.

[Driver Link](https://github.com/mtorromeo/r8168)

Comment: Which version of Fedora are you running?  What kernel version do you have?

Comment: @rickhg12hs I am using Fedora 35. kernel: 5.15.6-200.fc35.x86_64

Comment: Pretty sure the driver is already in your kernel.  So, when the kernel is updated, you also get the updated driver.  Is something not working?

Comment: @rickhg12hs r8168 driver in proprietary driver. And fedora doesn't include it. r8169 driver is included with kernel. Which is faulty. Hence, asking for akmod-r8168 driver.

Comment: Well, Fedora does have DKMS if you want to use it.  I notice that [RealTek's Driver](https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-pci-express-software) is advertised to work up to kernel version 5.6 ... I don't know if that will be a problem.  You may also need to deal with signing the kernel module if you use secure boot - not a big deal, but requires several steps initially.